# squid: Unable to allow 10.10.11.0/24 but 10.10.11.0/23 works

Tags: debian, squid, subnet, access-control-list, ipv4

Im unable to make a working acl with CIDR over `/23`
 (squid 5.7 on Debian)
For example i got this config (working):

```
acl servers src 10.10.11.0/23
http_access allow servers
...    
http_access deny all
```

Now i change `/23` to `/24` and my client on `10.10.11.130` gets `Forbidden 403`
I have tried `10.10.11.130/32` aswell

Theres nothing other named "servers" or something like this in the config.

What am i doing wrong?

Logs on `/23`:

```
TCP_MISS/200
```

Logs on `/24`:

```
TCP_DENIED/403
```

Comment: have you tried standard cidr like /8 /16? I mean some wired bug existed that only allowed to use cidr that can be halfed by 2 (devided)

Comment: /8 /9 /10 /12 /16 /22 all working.
Not working: 10.10.11.0/24, 10.10.11.128/25, 10.10.11.128/26 (for example)
10.10.11.130/32 not working.

Comment: please edit your question instead writing into the commentary section please

Answer (score 1):

I solved it after debugging the connection with tcpdump..
Every request was NATed..and asked by my openwrt router and not the device (10.10.11.130)
After disabling NATing for this Network the request came from the real device:

NAT:

```
router > fwproxy 3128
```

No NAT:

```
10.10.10.130 > fwproxy 3128
```

Comment: omg thats some kind of errors, where you really dislike your own equipment ;)